Assistance Needed with Converting SharePoint Document Library Files to URN for Autodesk Forge Viewer
I am currently working on a project that requires converting documents from a SharePoint Document Library to be viewable in the Autodesk Forge Viewer. To achieve this, I have found the React NPM package react-forge-viewer, which requires a URN to display Revit files in the 3D viewer.
However, when attempting to convert the document file to a URN using a Power Automate flow, I encountered the following error:

Below is the URL I am trying to use to convert the file to a URN, but it is not functioning as expected:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket/objects/SnowdonTowersSampleSite.rvt/signed?useCdn=true&access=write
I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue.
Thank you in advance for your help.
